# Is there a way to set/unset the execute bit on a file in osx 10.6.8 without using terminal (or bypassing it)?

Tags: terminal, snow-leopard, filesystem

I would like to do the following:

```
chmod +x filename.txt
```

without using the terminal.  Is there a way to bypass the terminal and invoke a kernel system call ? I'd rather not write a program to do this.  Instead I was wondering if I could somehow simulate a terminal with (perhaps) an application besides terminal to invoke system calls.

I have already tried doing Command Key + i on the file to show the information GUI.  However there is no option for setting the execute bit.

Would appreciate help from os x administrator experts in the community.

Comment: Did you try Automator ?

Answer (score 3):

[**Keyboard Maestro**](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) can do this using the following macro, which runs `chmod +x` on each item in the current Finder selection:

[image: ⌃⇧X: For Each Item in the Collection Execute Actions The items in the (fixed) Finder selection; Execute Shell Script; chmod +x "$KMVAR_File".]

<sup>[Download Macro](http://cl.ly/Sq8u)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You could use an SFTP client (like CyberDuck, Transmit etc) to give you a Finder-like view of your files with a GUI interface for permission control to include the x bit.

With [Transmit](http://panic.com/transmit/) you don't even need to make a SSH connection, you can just browse locally.  Not sure if any of the free clients offer this feature.

Answer (score 2):

[Path Finder](http://cocoatech.com/pathfinder/) a Finder replacement has a Get Info that allows you to change the execution bit,